# IP Checksum with insufficient number of bits

Tags: ip, checksum

I have to calculate and verify checksums for IP packets (I am writing a router in C).  The struct that represents an IP header has a 16 bit checksum but the total number of bits in the struct is not evenly divisible by 16 -- it is 8 bits short.

My question is this.  Do I read the struct 16 bits at a time and pad the last set of bits with zeroes to calculate the checksum?

Answer (score 0):

If you had the wrong number of bits, you would pad zero bits to the *end* of the data.

**However**, IP calculates over the header fields and thus *always* has a multiple of 16 bits on which to calculate the checksum.  TCP sometimes needs an extra byte of zero at the end of the data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum